# UITableView Custom Cell Height Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm learning how to use UIKit programmatically, and I created a custom UITableViewCell, but my row height isn't registering.

I keep getting this error

*[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously
suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view.
We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.*

I can't seem to understand/find where the issue with my code is, even after googling the error.

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let contacts = ContactAPI.getContacts()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    var safeArea: UILayoutGuide!
    //let contentView = UIView()
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        safeArea = view.layoutMarginsGuide

        setUpTable()
        setUpNavigation()
    }
    
    func setUpTable(){
        view.addSubview(tableView)
                
        //populate with data
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        //turn off autoresizing
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        //Layout Configs
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       
    }
    
    func setUpNavigation(){
        navigationItem.title = "Contacts"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .gray
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        //cell.textLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
        cell.contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }
}
```

**CustomCell:**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(profileImage)
        subView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        subView.addSubview(jobTitleLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(subView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(flagImage)
        
        profileImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
        profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:70).isActive = true
        profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:70).isActive = true
        
        subView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.profileImage.trailingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
        subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
        subView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:40).isActive = true
        
        nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.subView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.subView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.subView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        jobTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        jobTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.subView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        jobTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        jobTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.subView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        flagImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:26).isActive = true
        flagImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:26).isActive = true
        flagImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant:-20).isActive = true
        flagImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    //Profile Image
    let profileImage: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        return img
    }()
    
    //Name
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.textColor = .gray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    //Job Title
    let jobTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .gray
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    //Container for Name and Job Title
    let subView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    
    //Country Flag
    let flagImage: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        return img
    }()
    
    var contact:Contact? {
        didSet{
            guard let contactItem = contact else {return}
            
            if let name = contactItem.name{
                profileImage.image = UIImage(named: name)
                nameLabel.text = name
            }
            
            if let jobTitle = contactItem.jobTitle{
                jobTitleLabel.text = "\(jobTitle)"
            }
            
            if let country = contactItem.country{
                flagImage.image = UIImage(named: country)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have this `jobTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true` repeated twice.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the repeated parts but nothing changed.

Comment: Never said it would fix the error. I just noticed the typo. However, I only get that error when I do not have  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` in my code. From the code you have posted it does not look like you have implemented `UITableViewDelegate`. If you implement that then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented the `UITableViewDelegate`

In your `setupTable()` add the line

`tableView.delegate = self`

Then change your extension from

`extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {`

to `extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {`